# How to open App when click a website link (Firebase Dynamic Link)

Tags: ios, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

Let's say I've got a website: www.mywebsite.com
Is it possible to tell Firebase Dynamic Link to be triggered when I open the www.mywebsite.com.

I mean, lets say somebody from the website, www.mywebsite.com (www.mywebsite.com/product123) share a link.
If someone opens the link I want to redirect them to my native app, BUT with Firebase Dynamic Link I should share www.mywebsite.link.page to make this possible (as far as I am understanding it)

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like, according to your question, you're looking for a way to add a custom domain to your Dynamic Link. This is a commonly requested feature, but it hasn't been added yet.